# Combining / Merging 2 observables into one

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript, observable

Im trying to combine 2 Observables. The first observable Holds a `ShoppingCart` class and the second holds a list of `ShoppingItems`. I want to map the observable with shopping cart items (`Observable<ShoppingItems`) to the instance variable within the `ShoppingCart` class called `shoppingList$`.

**Observable 1:** `Observable<ShoppingCart>`

Here's  a snippet of the shopping cart class.

```
export class ShoppingCart {
private shoppingList$: Observable<ShoppingItems> 
private selectedIndex: number;
... etc
}
```

**Observable 2:** `Observable<ShoppingItems[]>` 
    private observable: Observable

Here is the function I am using.

```
retrieveShoppingCartComplete(shoppingCartId: string): Observable<ShoppingCart> {

/**Returns the requested shopping cart, with the Ids of the shopping items in an array called shoppingCart.ShoppingItems*/
    let shoppingCart$ = this.retrieveShoppingCart_AsEntity(shoppingCartId); 


/** returns an Observable<ShoppingItems[]> of the requested ShoppingItems as entitys*/
    let shoppingItems$ = shoppingCart$.map(shoppingCart => this.leS.retrieveShoppingItemsComplete(shoppingCart.ShoppingItemsIds))

   return shoppingCart$.combineAll(shoppingItems$);
}
```

However the method above returns an `Observable<[ShoppingCart | ShoppingItems[]]>` not an `Observable<ShoppingCart>` with the `Observable<ShoppingItems>` array assigned to the `shoppingList$` instance variable in the `ShoppingCart` Class

Answer (score 0):

I think `combineAll` is not what you need here. I'd use `flatMap` to chain two service calls like this:

```
retrieveShoppingCartComplete(shoppingCartId: string): Observable<ShoppingCart> {
    return this.retrieveShoppingCart_AsEntity(shoppingCartId)
        .flatMap(shoppingCart => {
            shoppingCart.shoppingList$ = this.leS.retrieveShoppingItemsComplete(shoppingCart.ShoppingItemsIds)
        })
}
```